# Adjusting the x-axis scale on a bar chart in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to adjust the scale of the x-axis so that the values are closer together, but I am not able to do so.

I need the output to be like this photo:

[image]

However, what I actually get is the photo below:

[image]

Here's the code I have written to reproduce this error:

```
    x = [0.1 1 10 100 1000 10000];
    y = [1.9904   19.8120   82.6122   93.0256   98.4086   99.4016];
    figure;
    bar(x,y);
    ylabel('Y values');
    xlabel('X values');
    set(gca,'XTick', [0.1 1 10 100 1000 10000])
```

How can I adjust the x-axis so that it looks like the first photo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your data has such huge dynamic range, and because of the linear behaviour of the `x` axis, your graph is naturally going to appear like that.  One compromise that I can suggest is that you transform your `x` data so that it gets mapped to a smaller scale, then remap your `x` data so that it falls onto a small **exponential** scale.  After, simply plot the data using this remapped scale, then rename the `x` ticks so that they have the same values as your `x` data.  To do this, I would take the `log10` of your data first, then apply an exponential to this data.  In this way, you are scaling the `x` co-ordinates down to a smaller dynamic range.  When you apply the exponential to this smaller range, the `x` co-ordinates will then spread out in a gradual way where higher values of `x` will certainly make the value go farther along the `x`-axis, but not too far away like you saw in your original plot.

As such, try something like this:

```
x = [0.1 1 10 100 1000 10000]; %// Define data
y = [1.9904   19.8120   82.6122   93.0256   98.4086   99.4016];
xplot = (1.25).^(log10(x)); %// Define modified x values
figure;
bar(xplot,y); %// Plot the bar graph on the modified scale
set(gca,'XTick', xplot); %// Define ticks only where the bars are located
set(gca,'XTickLabel', x); %// Rename these ticks to our actual x data
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Note that you'll have to play around with the base of the exponential, which is 1.25 in what I did, to suit your data.  Obviously, the bigger the dynamic range of your `x` data, the **smaller** this exponent will have to be in order for your data to be closer to each other.

---

## Edit from your comments

From your comments, you want the bars to be equidistant in between neighbouring bars.  As such, you simply have to make the `x` axis linear in a small range, from... say... 1 to the total number of `x` values.  You'd then apply the same logic where we rename the ticks on the `x` axis so that they are from the true `x` values instead.  As such, you only have to change one line, which is `xplot`.  The other lines should stay the same.  Therefore:

```
x = [0.1 1 10 100 1000 10000]; %// Define data
y = [1.9904   19.8120   82.6122   93.0256   98.4086   99.4016];
xplot = 1:numel(x); %// Define modified x values
figure;
bar(xplot,y); %// Plot the bar graph on the modified scale
set(gca,'XTick', xplot); %// Define ticks only where the bars are located
set(gca,'XTickLabel', x); %// Rename these ticks to our actual x data
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: Thank Ray,
but I am wondering if x = [ 0.1 1 5 10 12 15] .. how can I manage x axis values? because I use random values for x. Also how can I make an equal distance between each bar?

Comment: @User436823 - Do you want the bars to be equal distance to each other always?  If that's the case, just plot between 1 to as many values that you have of `x`, then rename the ticks so that they are the same as your `x` values.  If this is really what you want, then I will modify my post to reflect that.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @User436823 - Done.  Good luck!

Comment: @User436823 - My pleasure!  All the best.